# SCM - How does spring deal with many version

Tags: spring, version-control

Spring framework has many dependencies and many versions.

**For example**: project A -> version 5.0.0

project A -> version 4.x.x

I saw their repository and faced with many branches, like these:

3.x, 4.x, 5.x

My question is:

If there is a bug that exists in versions 3.x, 4.x, 5.x, how they will fix it?
They will fix in all branches? how "Version Control works in this case? They maintain many branchs to be able to fix bugs or do some improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the SCM system and the strategy.

If you e.g. use **git**, you can use `git cherry-pick`.

This command copies a commit to another branch.

For example you can fix it in 3.x (lets say `abcd` is the commit hash), you checkout the `4.x` branch and run

```
git cherry-pick abcd
```

You can also use merging (in git).

You could e.g. have a branch where both `3.x` and `4.x` branch off (or an empty branch).

Then you apply this fix in that branch.

Finally, you can merge this branch into `3.x` and `4.x`